# Add Junit test in Bamboo

Tags: unit-testing, junit, bamboo

I have project already building by Bamboo but this project doesn't have tests and I want to add some junit tests to this project.

How can I do that? I searched on internet but I couldn't find anything useful. I need detailed info about that because I am very new about Bamboo.

Thanks.

Comment: If the test cases are already written, you can make it executed by checking the checkbox in maven build task. If you want the test case to execute separately, you can also use a Junit parser plugin as a bamboo task.

Comment: Thank you for your response.